# Parse beforeDelete for User

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using a similar code for all of my other classes(ones I created), beforeDelete & afterDelete works fine on them.

But for the class User these 2 functions dont seem to work. Is there a special thing for deleting objects in User class? Is there another way to do it?

Here is my code:

main.js

```
Parse.Cloud.define("delete_user", delete_object.deleteUser);
Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete("User", triggers.userBeforeDelete);
Parse.Cloud.afterDelete("User", triggers.userAfterDelete);
```

delete.js

```
function deleteObject(className, objectId) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query(className);
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    query.get(objectId ,{
        success: function(result){
            var object = result;
            object.destroy({
                success: function(myObject) {
                    promise.resolve(myObject);
                // The object was deleted from the Parse Cloud.
                },
                error: function(myObject, error) {
                    console.log('Error couldnt delete the object ' + error.message);
                    promise.reject(error);
                }
            });  
        },
        error: function(newObject, error){
            console.log("Error couldnt get the object: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            promise.reject(error);
        }
    });

    return promise;
}

function deleteUser(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    console.log('Entered deleteUser');

    var objectId = request.params.objectId;
    var returnValue = deleteObject('User', objectId).then(function() {
        if (returnValue) {
            console.log('userDelete completed');
            response.success(true);
        } else {
            response.error(returnValue);
        }
    }, 
    function (error) {
        console.error('Request failed with response code ' + error.status);
        response.error(false);
    }); 
}
```

triggers.js

```
function userBeforeDelete(request) {
    console.log('Entered userBeforeDelete');
}

function userAfterDelete(request) {
    console.log('Entered userAfterDelete');
}
```

Normally it should be printing 'Entered deleteUser' and then 'Entered userBeforeDelete' and after 'userDelete completed'

But it is skipping 'Entered userBeforeDelete' and just printing out 'Entered deleteUser' & 'userDelete completed' and it successfully deletes the user.

I have used the same code for other classes such as Comments, Cards, Contents and they all work fine. 
I want to be able to do some stuff before deleting and after deleting the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "User" (the way you would do it for a programmer-defined class called User), try `Parse.User`, as in....

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
```